# Flink Azure blob state configuration

Tags: azure, kubernetes, hadoop, azure-blob-storage, apache-flink

I have apache flink deployed to AWS EKS (1.21) with version 1.17-SNAPSHOT and state storage in AWS S3. This setup works great.

I am now trying to deploy the same version to Azure AKS (1.22 - minimum available version for AKS) and store the state in Azure Blob.

In both cases I use the [apache flink kubernetes operator](https://github.com/apache/flink-kubernetes-operator), version 1.3.1.

If I disable checkpoints and savepoints my application works great.

Once enabled, I get the following error at job manager startup:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.hadoop.security.JniBasedUnixGroupsMappingWithFallback not found
at org.apache.flink.fs.shaded.hadoop3.org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:2592) ~[?:?]
at org.apache.flink.fs.shaded.hadoop3.org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2686) ~[?:?]
at org.apache.flink.fs.shaded.hadoop3.org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2712) ~[?:?]
at org.apache.flink.fs.shaded.hadoop3.org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups.<init>(Groups.java:107) ~[?:?]
at org.apache.flink.fs.shaded.hadoop3.org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups.<init>(Groups.java:102) ~[?:?]
at org.apache.flink.fs.shaded.hadoop3.org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups.getUserToGroupsMappingService(Groups.java:451) ~[?:?]
at org.apache.flink.fs.shaded.hadoop3.org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.initialize(UserGroupInformation.java:338) ~[?:?]
at org.apache.flink.fs.shaded.hadoop3.org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.ensureInitialized(UserGroupInformation.java:300) ~[?:?]
at org.apache.flink.fs.shaded.hadoop3.org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getCurrentUser(UserGroupInformation.java:575) ~[?:?]
at org.apache.flink.fs.shaded.hadoop3.org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.NativeAzureFileSystem.initialize(NativeAzureFileSystem.java:1425) ~[?:?]
at org.apache.flink.fs.azurefs.AbstractAzureFSFactory.create(AbstractAzureFSFactory.java:78) ~[?:?]
at org.apache.flink.core.fs.PluginFileSystemFactory.create(PluginFileSystemFactory.java:62) ~[flink-dist-1.17-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.17-SNAPSHOT]
at org.apache.flink.core.fs.FileSystem.getUnguardedFileSystem(FileSystem.java:508) ~[flink-dist-1.17-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.17-SNAPSHOT]
at org.apache.flink.core.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:409) ~[flink-dist-1.17-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.17-SNAPSHOT]
at org.apache.flink.core.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:274) ~[flink-dist-1.17-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.17-SNAPSHOT]
at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.filesystem.FsCheckpointStorageAccess.<init>(FsCheckpointStorageAccess.java:67) ~[flink-dist-1.17-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.17-SNAPSHOT]
at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.storage.FileSystemCheckpointStorage.createCheckpointStorage(FileSystemCheckpointStorage.java:324) ~[flink-dist-1.17-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.17-SNAPSHOT]
at org.apache.flink.runtime.checkpoint.CheckpointCoordinator.<init>(CheckpointCoordinator.java:333) ~[flink-dist-1.17-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.17-SNAPSHOT]
at org.apache.flink.runtime.checkpoint.CheckpointCoordinator.<init>(CheckpointCoordinator.java:248) ~[flink-dist-1.17-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.17-SNAPSHOT]
at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.DefaultExecutionGraph.enableCheckpointing(DefaultExecutionGraph.java:524) ~[flink-dist-1.17-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.17-SNAPSHOT]
at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.DefaultExecutionGraphBuilder.buildGraph(DefaultExecutionGraphBuilder.java:321) ~[flink-dist-1.17-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.17-SNAPSHOT]
at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultExecutionGraphFactory.createAndRestoreExecutionGraph(DefaultExecutionGraphFactory.java:163) ~[flink-dist-1.17-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.17-SNAPSHOT]
at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.SchedulerBase.createAndRestoreExecutionGraph(SchedulerBase.java:365) ~[flink-dist-1.17-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.17-SNAPSHOT]
at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.SchedulerBase.<init>(SchedulerBase.java:210) ~[flink-dist-1.17-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.17-SNAPSHOT]
at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultScheduler.<init>(DefaultScheduler.java:136) ~[flink-dist-1.17-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.17-SNAPSHOT]
at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultSchedulerFactory.createInstance(DefaultSchedulerFactory.java:152) ~[flink-dist-1.17-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.17-SNAPSHOT]
at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.DefaultSlotPoolServiceSchedulerFactory.createScheduler(DefaultSlotPoolServiceSchedulerFactory.java:119) ~[flink-dist-1.17-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.17-SNAPSHOT]
at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobMaster.createScheduler(JobMaster.java:371) ~[flink-dist-1.17-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.17-SNAPSHOT]
at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobMaster.<init>(JobMaster.java:348) ~[flink-dist-1.17-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.17-SNAPSHOT]
at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.factories.DefaultJobMasterServiceFactory.internalCreateJobMasterService(DefaultJobMasterServiceFactory.java:123) ~[flink-dist-1.17-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.17-SNAPSHOT]
at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.factories.DefaultJobMasterServiceFactory.lambda$createJobMasterService$0(DefaultJobMasterServiceFactory.java:95) ~[flink-dist-1.17-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.17-SNAPSHOT]
at org.apache.flink.util.function.FunctionUtils.lambda$uncheckedSupplier$4(FunctionUtils.java:112) ~[flink-dist-1.17-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.17-SNAPSHOT]
at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
```

I followed this guide: https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.16/docs/deployment/filesystems/azure/ , the `azure-fs-hadoop` is properly configured.

I tried settings `hadoop.flink.flink.hadoop.hadoop.security.group.mapping: org.apache.flink.fs.shaded.hadoop3.org.apache.hadoop.security.JniBasedUnixGroupsMappingWithFallback` in flink_conf.yaml

The checkpoint and savepoint configuration:

```
state.checkpoints.dir: wasb://checkpoints@<account>.blob.core.windows.net/<cp_path>
state.savepoints.dir: wasb://checkpoints@<account>.blob.core.windows.net/<sp_path>
```

If I try to set the properties this way, I get messages about anonymous access:

```
state.checkpoints.dir: wasb://checkpoints@$<account>.blob.core.windows.net/<cp_path>
state.savepoints.dir: wasb://checkpoints@$<account>.blob.core.windows.net/<sp_path>
```

Message:

```
The account access key is not configured for wasb://checkpoints@$<account>.blob.core.windows.net/<cp_path>. Now try anonymous access.
```

any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue should be fixed in flink 1.17.1 or higher: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-31612